# Why does Spark shuffle the data while joining two partitioned & bucketed tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, table-partitioning, bucketing

I am trying to create a view on top of two tables.

Table 1:
Partitioned by col1
Bucketed by col2 (no of buckets: 3600)

Table 2:
Partitioned by col1
Bucketed by col2 ( no of buckets:3600)

View:
Table1
Join
Table2
On col1=col1
And col2=col2

Here,

When I run query on top of this view, data for both tables are shuffled by hashpartitioning(col1,col2)

I am wondering why this should happen.
My understanding is since data is already partitioned and bucketed in equal no of partitions/buckets, spark should know where data exists and it should just do sort-merge-join without shuffling.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

I tried to set various spark properties related bucketing, but still it shuffles data.

Comment: I think it would need to repartition it by the two columns you are joining on, since bucketing probably does not help it there.